# How does getUserPrincipal() work? When should i use it?

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm kinda new to Java EE and trying to learn it. So it's unclear to me how exactly `request.getUserPrincipal()` works. Where it gets Principal object? When and how this object is created?

So let's assume I have a login form that passes user name and password in HTTP POST request. In my servlet I have to take this data and compare it to records in my database. If find one, create user object with his name and some other data. In this case, when do I need to call `getUserPrincipal()`? And do i really need to call it, because there's already some logic which return a user object? And how this method will get `Principal` object for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.getUserPrincipal()` will be populated when you use container managed authentication. Since you have implemented your own authentication that method will return `null` and can be safely ignored.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Didn't know about container managed authentication, so now i'm gonna read something about this.
And another question then: is it a good idea to implement your own auth and use it instead of container managed auth?

Comment: Generally, rolling your own implementation of a security feature is a much high risk approach than using an existing implementation with a proven track record.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a little late to answer, just in case :

In JEE servers, Principal and Subject objects are linked to your HttpRequest with JAAS login module. To implements your own authentication you have to implement your own JAAS login module.

Then you will get naturally your own implementation of Principal.
And then your authentication and authorisation to some pages or urls will be managed with configurations on your JEE Server. Example, you can add security contraints to your web.xml to allow or not somes urls like below :

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

More about JAAS : https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/security/jaas-tutorials.html

This mecanism exists since the beggining of JEE, but few peoples knows how to use it.